# How do I hide a particular control in File-open dialog? (A dialog created using CFileDialog)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Below is the code which I used to create a File-Open Dialog. This works fine, no problem in the code but for some reason i wish to hide the change your view control (I have highlighted that in the attachment)

```
    CString strFilter = _T(".mp3");
    CFileDialog fileDialog(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT |
        OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_LONGNAMES, strFilter, NULL, 0, TRUE);
    CString szStrTitle = _T("Select the file");
    fileDialog.m_ofn.lpstrTitle = szStrTitle;
    TCHAR *filenameBuffer = new TCHAR[4000 * 1000];
    filenameBuffer[0] = 0;
    fileDialog.m_ofn.lpstrFile = filenameBuffer;
    fileDialog.m_ofn.nMaxFile = 4000 * 1000;
    fileDialog.DoModal();
```

Being a newbie there can be silly mistakes in asking the question, ignore them and please help  in achieving the desired result
Thank you.[image: File-Open]

Comment: `strFilter` should be `"mp3|*.mp3||"` Note the random characters that show up in the bottom-right side.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I saw that later on & made the necessary changes but thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, the proper way of customizing common file dialog is to use `IFileDialogCustomize`. This interface is fully documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialogcustomize

For your specific case you'll need to use `IFileDialogCustomize::RemoveControlItem()`

You can also use `IFileDialogCustomize::SetControlItemState()` which allows you to hide the target control.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I was just wondering how to get the ID of that particular control

Comment: Just get the ID of the control you'd like to remove/hide using Microsoft Spy++. I'm pretty sure the ID is defined in some header file in Platform SDK but it is a hard way).

Comment: That's a `DirectUIHWND` class. Spy++ won't work on it.